# Use a status field to change the color of a promoted link

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links, status, color-field

Is it possible to use another field to automatically change the color of the tile based on that field.

Meaning, I have three fields in a list one is the calculation of the other two.

`Actual-Target=Gap`, if the GAP is a negative number I want the tile to be red if it is the same or more I want it green.

I do not want to go into the promoted link to make the change I want to update field and have it change for me.

Can this be done?